# How are descriptors matched with each other in SIFT?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, sift, descriptor

**INTRODUCTION:**

I am trying to get the intuition of matching descriptors with each other. I am aware of methods in python opencv to find key points, draw them or match them with images.

**WHAT I WANT TO ASK:**

My question is about getting the intuition of descriptors matching with each other. How do we compare them to see if we found a match ?

**WHAT I ALREADY KNOW:**

A descriptor in SIFT is 128 dimension vector (16x16 size window divided into 4x4 sub blocks with each individual block being a bin size 8 histogram)

Comment: Perhaps see https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/10/detailed-guide-powerful-sift-technique-image-matching-python/

Comment: Distances are computed by summing the difference between each element of the 128-D vectors according to a given norm such as L2 (sum of squared differences). Smaller differences mean better match.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of keypoint description matching is based on the euclidian distance between the descriptors. Lesser the distance higher the probability of matching.

[Different distances](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gad12cefbcb5291cf958a85b4b67b6149f) like L1-normal or L2-normal are used to find the closest matching descriptor. Also, different strategies are used to optimize matching.